# Converting jpg, jpeg, png to webp in Linux Command Line

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, compression, webp

After running:

`$ sudo apr-get install webp`

I ran the following script:

`$ for file in *.jpg *.jpeg *.png; do cwebp "$file" -o "${file%.*}.webp"; cp --preserve=mode "$file" "${file%.*}.webp"; done`

All files within the current directory were converted to webp, however, the size was exactly the same. It was as if it didn't actually compress the file and instead just changed the ending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cp --preserve=mode "$file" "${file%.*}.webp";
```

Why do you need the "cp" line? It's just copying the jpeg/png to the webp file from the previous command and that's why you're seeing no change in file size.

Comment: I was also wanting to preserve file permissions. Whenever I did it the first time it had different permissions for the other group. I took it out and it fixed it, thank you.